# Concurrent requests with Ring/Jetty and InputStream

Tags: multithreading, clojure, jetty, inputstream, ring

For a project I'm using `InputStream` as response body for Ring. This works great, however, the server does not respond to any additional requests when it is streaming a single response.

For example, when I start five concurrent requests only the first one starts. Then the next, and so on.

This is a simplified version of my code. I'm using `clj-http` to get an input stream of a Wikipedia image and pass it directly to the response.

```
(ns streaming.server
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]
            [clj-http.client :as client]))

(defn app [request]
  (let [large-image-url "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/LARGE_elevation.jpg"]
    (client/get large-image-url {:as :stream})))

(defn -main [& args]
  (run-jetty app {:port 3000 :join? false}))
```

Is this expected behaviour? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your client is using persistent http connections